# Fetching data from Mongo Atlas using Azure Function

Tags: mongoose, azure-functions, mongoose-schema

I have created a collection on Mongo Atlas and I am able to add and fetch data using Postman. I tried to move this code to an Azure Function but the code doesn't seem to work. I get a status 200 on my Postman, but no data.

Note - I had a hard time trying to figure out how connections and models are shared between functions inside the app. I referred this blog [to make my progress](http://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-azure-functions-and-mongodb.html).

1. This is what my current folder in Azure server at "[your-function-name].scm.azurewebsites.net" looks like.
   [image]
2. Here are my file details

```
// ./connection/index.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// mongoose connection
const MONGOOSE_URI = mongodb+srv://[db_name]:[my_password]@cluster0.hberq.mongodb.net/email

mongoose.connect(MONGOOSE_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})

const connection = mongoose.connection
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Established connection to DB')
})
```

```
// ./models/email.model.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const emailSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  message: String,
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  isRead: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  isArchived: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

const EmailModel = mongoose.model('EmailModel', emailSchema)

module.exports = EmailModel
```

```
// ./getEmails (the main function I'm trying to host)
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema
const EmailModel = require('../models/email.model.js')

module.exports = async function(context, req) {
    context.log('print me') // test - this prints on console
    const test = await EmailModel.find()
    context.log(test) // test - no output here
    const test2 = await test.json()
    context.log(test2) // test - no output here

    EmailModel
        .find()
        .then(users => {
            context.log('Success!'); // no output here on console
            context.log(users)
            context.log(users.json())
            context.res = {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({ users })
            };
            context.done(); 
        })
}
```

3. Here is the output I get
   Note - Some errors started showing up (as seens in screenshot) after I was hit and trying a few tings with the code.
   [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

TLDR; I was not using `context` correctly to return the value. Instead of `context.json()`, `context.res()`, context.done(null, 'your response') and all other shenanigans I tried, it should have simply been:

```
context.res = {
  body: 'your response' // I can see 'your response' in Postman now.
}
```

The `./models/email.model.js` file I've shared above remains the same. I'll add the updated/ corrected version of `connection/index.js` and `./getEmails` for references if anybody else needs it.

```
// ./connection/index.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const MONGOOSE_URI = "mongodb+srv://[db_name]:[my_password]@456@cluster0.hberq.mongodb.net/email"

mongoose.connect(MONGOOSE_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
})

const connection = mongoose.connection
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Established connection to DB')
})

return connection
```

```
// ./getEmails
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const EmailModel = require('../models/email.model.js')
require('../connection/index.js')

module.exports = async function(context, req) {
    const emails = await EmailModel.find()
    context.res = {
        body: emails
    }
    context.done()
}
```